# JSTL accessing c:set variable and convert with SimpleDateFormat

Tags: jsp, jstl

I have the following sourcecode:

```
<c:set var="runtimeEnd" value="${content.valueList.Promotion[0].value.RuntimeEnd}"/>
```

which is a number in jsp and stands for a date for example: 1425769140000

how do i access this variable in Java? imean when i do the following it wont even load the page anymore:

```
<% out.println(${runtimeEnd}); %>
```

I would like to insert the variable into the following JAVA code to display the date

```
<% SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMMMMMMM yyyy");
out.println(simpleDateFormat.format(${runtimeEnd})); %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you want to use scriplets? Do the work with jstl library if you have started with it.

[JSTL Format Date](http://www.codejava.net/java-ee/jstl/jstl-format-tag-formatdate) library seems is what you need.

Example:

```
<c:set var="runtimeEnd" value="${content.valueList.Promotion[0].value.RuntimeEnd}"/>
<fmt:formatDate pattern="yyyy-MM-dd" value="${runtimeEnd}" />
```

P.S. To print a variable using jstl library, use `<c:out value="This will be printed" />` tag.

Scriplets approach:

Printing:

```
 <%=pageContext.getAttribute("runtimeEnd") %>
```

Formatting:

```
<% SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy"); 
String convertedDate = String.valueOf(pageContext.getAttribute("runtimeEnd"));
%>
<%=simpleDateFormat.format(convertedDate); %>
```

Comment: @TeaTime you can store it in a variable inside fmt tag using var key, like <fmt:formatDate ... var="myDate" />, and if you want to print it, pass it to out tag value.

Comment: <fmt:formatDate pattern="yyyy-MM-dd" value="${runtimeEnd}" var="test"/>
<c:out value="${test}" />  wont work :<

Comment: @TeaTime be sure what the value of runtimeEnd is a String, and you add the taglib declaration in the top of your jsp <%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>

Comment: @TeaTime check my Edit.

Comment: Thanks for your help :) the thing was i forgot to add the fmt library. Also the simpleDateFormat way is unneccessarry since the expression language works great